# How do I add random colors?

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

Now that I have cubes, my next thing to do is to add to each cube a random color, but I am having trouble making it on each cube. As you can see in the output of my code, every face of the cube has the same color, and the sides are different. I have tried different things in my code, but sometimes the cubes are all the same color.

I want to make the cubes have different colors.

My Desired Output:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

verticies = ((0.5, -0.5, -0.5), (0.5, 0.5, -0.5), (-0.5, 0.5, -0.5), (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
             (0.5, -0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5), (-0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
edges = ((0,1), (0,3), (0,4), (2,1),(2,3), (2,7), (6,3), (6,4),(6,7), (5,1), (5,4), (5,7))

surfaces = (
    (0,1,2,3),
    (3,2,7,6),
    (6,7,5,4),
    (4,5,1,0),
    (1,5,7,2),
    (4,0,3,6)
    )

colors = (
    (1,0,0),
    (0,1,0),
    (0,0,1),
    (0,1,0),
    (1,1,1),
    (0,1,1),
    (1,0,0),
    (0,1,0),
    (0,0,1),
    (1,0,0),
    (1,1,1),
    (0,1,1),
    )

def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    x = 0
    for surface in surfaces:
        x+=1
        for vertex in surface:
            glColor3fv(colors[x])
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
    glEnd()
    
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
    glEnd()
    
def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    gluPerspective(60, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 500)
    button_down = False
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)  
    modelMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
    
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)

    while True:
        glPushMatrix()
        glLoadIdentity()
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    glTranslatef(-1, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    glTranslatef(1, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    glTranslatef(0, 1, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    glTranslatef(0, -1, 0)
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if button_down == True:
                    glRotatef(event.rel[1], 1, 0, 0)
                    glRotatef(event.rel[0], 0, 1, 0)

        for event in pygame.mouse.get_pressed():
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                button_down = True
            elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
                button_down = False

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glMultMatrixf(modelMatrix)
        modelMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)

        glLoadIdentity()
        glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)
        glMultMatrixf(modelMatrix)
        
        for i in range(5):
            glPushMatrix()
            glTranslate(-2+i, 0, 0)
            Cube()
            glPopMatrix()
        
        glPopMatrix()        
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an array of 6 colors:

```py
colors = [(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1)]
```

Do **not** set the color for every vertex:

```py
def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    x = 0
    for surface in surfaces:
        x+=1
        for vertex in surface:
            # glColor3fv(colors[x])           <--- DELTETE
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
    glEnd()
```

but set the color for every cube:

```py
for i in range(5):
    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslate(-2+i, 0, 0)
    glColor3fv(colors[i])                   # <--- INSERT
    Cube()
    glPopMatrix()
```

[image]